# (Numpy) Index list to boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Input:

1. array length (Integer)
2. indexes (Set or List)

Output:

A boolean numpy array that has a value 1 for the indexes 0 for the others.

---

Example:

Input: `array_length=10, indexes={2,5,6}`

Output:

```
[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]
```

Here is a my simple implementation:

```
def indexes2booleanvec(size, indexes):
    v = numpy.zeros(size)
    for index in indexes:
        v[index] = 1.0
    return v
```

Is there more elegant way to implement this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is to avoid the loop

```
In [7]: fill = np.zeros(array_length)     #  array_length = 10

In [8]: fill[indexes] = 1                 #  indexes = [2,5,6]

In [9]: fill
Out[9]: array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it (in one line):

```
np.isin(np.arange(array_length), indexes)
```

However this is slower than Zero's solution.